# Laravel return redirect() method is not redirecting

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update a customer in the "public function update(Customer $customer)" method when I check the database, the update is running smoothly but when it hit the redirect(), it throws an error. When I dd($customer->id) after the $custome, it has the same id.  [This is the method in the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOGm3.png),[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT2kq.png),[This is where the error happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMrXD.png)

I have been looking through the code to find the reason. I'd be so grateful if someone could help me on this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the redirect route depicted in the docs
and pass the id to the route if the customers route

```
return redirect()->route('customers', ['id' => $customer->id]);
```